# Can the drain pipe in my bathroom vanity be turned to the side?

Tags: bathroom

Can the drain pipe in my bathroom vanity be turned to the side so that the middle of the sink can be further to the right.  I don't want ot have to move the hole in the wall.  I currently have a 30" vanity, and I want to buy a 48" vanity.  The center of the new vanity would be 24" as opposed to the current 15" center - a difference of 9".  I don't have any room to center the vanity since the toilet is just a little to the left of the vanity, so I would have to move it to the right - off center.

Answer (score 5):

This shouldn't be an issue. With the standard P-trap, you can probably turn it so that it goes toward the side instead of towards the wall to get your 9". The important rule of drainage is that it always needs to slope down (other than the traps at each fixture) and that you can't get too far from the vent. Neither of those should be an issue with the change you're making.

Do be sure that the new sink isn't significantly deeper than your existing one since that could result in the drain needing to go uphill to get to the wall (which water doesn't like to do).